# Regex to remove spaces

Tags: java, regex

How to write a regex to remove spaces in Java?

For example

```
Input  : "         "
Output : ""
---------------------
Input  : " "
Output : ""
```

Note that tabs and new lines should not be removed. Only spaces should be removed.

**Edit :**

How do we make a check ?

For example how to check in an *if* statement that  a String contains only spaces (any number of them)

```
  if(<statement>)
  {
              //inside statement
  }
```

For

```
   input = "                   "  or input = "    "
```

The control should should go inside *if* statement.

Comment: I've reworded your question a bit because "whitespace" *includes* tabs and newlines (and formfeeds etc.), so you should use the term "space" instead.

Answer (score 12):

The following will do it:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Alternatively:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" +", "");
```

In my benchmarks, the latter was ~40% faster than the former.

Comment: @ChristopheD: Oh yes it is :-) The `" "` is a regex that matches one space.

Answer (score 6):

```
String str = "     ";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do -

```
str = str.replace(" ", "");
str = str.replaceAll(" +", "");
```

If you check definition of `replace`and`replaceAll` method -

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
        return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
    }

public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
   return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

Unless you really need to replace a regular expression, `replaceAll` is definitely not our choice. Even if the performance is acceptable, the amount of objects created will impact the performance.

Not that much different from the `replaceAll()`, except that the compilation time of the **regular expression** (and most likely the execution time of the matcher) will be a bit shorter when in the case of `replaceAll()`.
Its better to use `replace` method rather `replaceAll`.

**Real-time comparison**

```
File size -> 6458400
replaceAll -> 94 millisecond
replace -> 78 millisecond
```

Comment: Can you time and compare `str.replace(" ", "");` versus `str.replaceAll(" +", "");`? That would be interesting.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - kindly check the test result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a simple `/[ ]+/`? This should be what you need.

Comment: Wont `\s` capture tabs also? Question doesn't want the tabs to be removed.

Comment: yeah that was dumb of me. Using a character class is probably more appropriate here.

Comment: You should at least use `+` as a quantifier (otherwise you'll do a "substitute nothing with nothing" operation on every location between two non-space characters in the entire string). Also, drop the brackets - it's only one character, so you don't need a character class (although one might argue it helps readability, and Java's regex engine will hopefully be smart enough to optimize it away).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I will leave the brackets because I like the flexibility and (as you mentioned) imporved readability. But I will add the plus though.